# UWP Binding dot weird behaviour

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I noticed a bit of a weird behaviour if i use a binding like

`Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource NavItemToCaptionConverter}}"`

My Listview (Full List code below) doesnt show any text for this textblock. If i remove the "dot" at runtime the view updates and shows all items correct. but then i get a "Unexpected token 'Comma' on compile time.

The collection i am binding onto is a Observable collection filled with a few Enum items.

I Cant find where i made my mistake. Does anyone have an idea?

Here the full code for the ListView:

```
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            ItemClick="OnNavigationBarItemClicked"
            ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationBarItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="10,15">
                        <Rectangle
                            Fill="DarkGray"
                            RadiusX="10"
                            RadiusY="10" />

                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="20,5"
                            FontSize="20"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource NavItemToCaptionConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Binding Path=.` is available for WPF. In general, we use Binding plus a space to bind the current context.

```
<TextBlock    Margin="20,5"
              FontSize="20"
              Foreground="Black"
              Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NavItemToCaptionConverter}}" />
```

> If i remove the "dot" at runtime the view updates and shows all items
>   correct. But then i get a "Unexpected token 'Comma' on compile time.

When you remove the "dot" at runtime, it will just refresh by the content of Binding. But in compile time, it will check the complete xaml code and see if there are any syntax errors. So the 'comma' will give an error.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained solution. I will test it today when i arrive at home and if succeded mark you as the answer. my +1 for this well written and fully explained answer!

Comment: OK, if it still can't show well after testing, please tell me.